# How to easily upgrade Karate Version?

Tags: karate

I would like to upgrade to Karate 0.9.0 which is released recently. How can i do this easily. My existing .pom file contains many dependencies in 0.8.0 version. Should i replace each with updated one? Or, is there a better way to do this?

And again, i can see many RC versions of dependencies in maven repository which one's stable?

And, Finally, Is there any separate dependency for KarateOptions? Because, I was using 0.8.0 and was not able to find any dependency jars for this.

Comment: Thanks Peter; Done for all now.

Comment: Using a spinning roundhouse kick to the head. Like Chuck Norris.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a maven question. But yes the recommended practice is to define a maven "property" once and then use it in the multiple places.

I'm surprised, because at the max you should have only 2.

```
<properties>
    <karate.version>0.9.0</karate.version>
</properties>  

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
        <artifactId>karate-apache</artifactId>
        <version>${karate.version}</version>
    </dependency>            
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
        <artifactId>karate-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>${karate.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>       
</dependencies>
```

And yes, `KarateOptions` is new in 0.9.0 - please read the release notes carefully and you don't even need to change that immediately when you upgrade: https://github.com/intuit/karate/releases/tag/v0.9.0

Comment: do you have a document showing how to migrate from Karate Apache 0.96 to Core 1.1.0 ?

Comment: @vianna77 yes: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide